# Using limit 1 in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I have the following sql query, which runs fine on MYSQL but gives error with Oracle and SQL Server because of the last limit 1 clause. My question is just - Is this limit 1 clause valid as per PostgreSQL and can I expect this to run successfully on Postgres?

```
select customer_number 
from
(select 
customer_number,
count(*) 
from
orders
group by 
customer_number 
order by count(*) desc limit 1) a
```

;

Answer (score 2):

`limit` is supported by some databases, but not all.  The SQL standard would be:

```
select customer_number
from orders
group by customer_number 
order by count(*) desc 
offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `sql server` you need to use `top`

```
select top 1 customer_number,count(*) 
from orders
group by customer_number 
order by count(*) desc
```